# What is the application that displays notifications in Lubuntu 12.04 and how to remove it?

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu, uninstall, notification

I get all the time notifications in the upper right corner and as a tray icon for all kind of actions, especially downloads.

What app is that in Lubuntu? (it is not notify-isd)

Is it possible to set what notifications to see? If not, how to remove this completely?

[image]

[image]

**Update edit**: 
Removing `notification-demon` (that being it seems the culprit, as an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/216736/47206) suggests) involves removing some important applications:

[image]

`Lubuntu-desktop` is a metapackage I guess. But what about removing `deluge` and `update-notifier`?

Can I add these back without getting back the notifier?? I do not want in any case to remove these two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that whether notifications are sent to the notifier daemon is on a program by program basis, and you would have to change that in your browser's settings (if possible). I am not 100% sure on this though. At any rate, to just remove notifications altogether:

```
sudo apt-get remove notification-daemon
```

You can also replace Lubuntu's notification system with XFCE's, which won't queue up your notifications, like the default one does. To do that:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4-notifyd
sudo apt-get remove notification-daemon
```

When doing it this way, it shouldn't ask to remove all those extra packages, as there will still be a notification system in place. I think it will still say it is uninstalling lubuntu-desktop, but that is because it is a meta package, meaning a package of packages. It won't remove your desktop. :-)

To change the settings for XFCE's notification system (timeouts, position, color), run this:

```
xfce4-notifyd-config
```

Comment: this has the following problem: too many applications are to be removed. see updated question

Comment: I updated my answer with a workaround.